# Sum up 2 values created dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a table created dynamically from the DB
[image]

I am trying to get sum up the value I `select` in the `own evaluation` field and the `value next to it in the same row` and display it in the `Gap` field right away.

The code I am using to fill those three columns is :

```
            echo "<td class='evaluation'>";
                echo "<select class='ownlevelselect' id='ownlevelselect' name='level-".$compi['Competence_ID']."' >";
                    echo "<option value=''>--</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.INDEX.'?categ='.$_GET['categ'].'&action='.$_GET['action'].'&subaction=viewlevels'.'&levels='.$compi['Competence_ID'].'">';
                echo '<img class="linkki" src="'.KUVAT.'paivita.gif" alt="'._("tiedot").'" title="'._("What is this?").'"/></a>';
                            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td class='mefly'>";
                echo $compi['actual_level'];        
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td class='gap'>";
                echo "<input type='text' readonly style='width:20px;'>";
            echo "</td>";
```

I tried this Jquery code as suggested by `silkfire`, but nothing changed..

```
$(function() {
       $(document).on('change', 'td.evaluation select', function() {
          var gap = $(this).val() + $(this).parent('tr').find('td.mefly').text();

          $(this).parent('tr').find('td.gap input:text').val(gap);
       });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: put event on select change and every time when select element is changed get current value and recalculate gap.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I need php to know that I want the adjecent value as well.

Comment: Auicsc: you can try adding a id for the col next to dropdown list box, in order to get the value of it from javascript.after which you can try Bojan`s idea

Comment: javascript will change html "gap" element. why php need to know that?

Comment: ya Bojan is right, i guess you just have to assign a change event for the select tag and write your logic to get sum up the value with that callback function which was associated with change event :) Happy coding

Comment: for finding currently selected option, instead of $(this).val() try $(this).find(":selected").val()

Comment: @BojanKovacevic thanks a lot for keeping on, but that fix you suggested did not help neither.

Comment: have you checked with alert that event is triggered?

Comment: Thanks @BojanKovacevic your suggestion about using find(":selected") helped a lot !!!

Comment: np, i see from chat it works now so gz :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give those three cells (td) a class name, e.g. "evaluation", "mefly" and "gap".

Then bind an event to the evaluation select:

```
$(function() {
   $(document).on('change', 'td.evaluation select', function() {
      var gap = parseInt($(this).val()) + parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('td.mefly').text());

      $(this).parents('tr').find('td.gap input:text').val(gap);
   });
});
```

Comment: the logic is great, but I dont know why nothing changes when I add it.

Comment: Have you added the classes to the table cells?

Comment: I did. I updated my post so that you can see the changes i made.

Comment: I'm using this:
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28102/discussion-between-silkfire-and-auicsc)

Comment: I change all the `parent` to `parents`?